# Prevent Windows 10 from Syncing Settings on Initial Setup

Tags: windows-10, sync, microsoft-account

I am stuck at setting up my laptop.
My goal is to install Windows 10 with my Microsoft account linked. No problem so far. But as soon as I sign up for the first time with my Microsoft account, my settings from my PC get synced. I've already disabled the feature on my PC, but the old settings are still in the cloud.

I know that I can disable the sync after set up, but then Windows already synced once.
Would it work to set it up with a local user without messing everything up by signing in later?

Comment: At the account creation, you are given an option to use pre-configured settings that are most commonly used, or an option to choose those settings individually.  You should pick that option.

Comment: I checked these settings atleast twice and deactivated every feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing create your user account without registering to a Microsoft account. Go in to the system after that is done and disable things you don't want updated when you sync with a live.com account. After that is done you have two options:

1) Integrate your system with your Microsoft account and see what happens (I think this would work fine as you have now configured everything with an admin account *not* to use synchronized settings.) It could fail but I think you'd be good.

2) Take things a step further and look up the things you don't want synced and disable those features in the registry.

Some additional material you may want to check before reinstalling would be these, just in case a setting was missed:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html
http://www.howtogeek.com/224847/how-to-set-up-and-configure-user-accounts-on-windows-10/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Won't adding the account afterwards, mess up the system?

Comment: @Cludch Nope, looks like it shouldn't: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5375-microsoft-account-switch-windows-10-a.html I've seen a few similar types of posts that indicate this is acceptable and shouldn't be buggy.

Comment: Yay! Glad it worked :) Have a great day.